# Can we create indexes on views in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can we create Indexes on a view in SQL Server 2008? I have heard about indexed view, which can give performance improvement, but the problem is data refresh on those views: Can it be auto updated, once data in base tables changes?

Comment: See this answer:  http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14903/10832

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indexed views are always in sync with the data in the underlying tables. You can read more about indexed views [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-indexed-views-the-basics/).

Be careful going overly enthusiastic with indexed views: they can be a real performance killer on heavily written tables.

Comment: And they need to be on indexes with "schemabinding"...right?

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli the view needs WITH SCHEMABINDING. No such option for indexes.

Comment: Yes...Sorry...Views, not indexes. My bad.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @spaghettidba, I had once encountered a problem with Materialised view in oracle 9, as the view was not refreshing automatically, and I had same impression with indexed view also if they are auto refreshed.

Comment: @Niraj In SQL Server indexed views are equivalent to Oracle's fast refresh materialized views. SQL Server offers no option for deferred refresh (which would be handy for enforcing constraints).